# File Upload Limit Issues laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a form which is used to upload a .zip file to my server. I can upload smaller ones (~200mb), but when I go to upload larger ones (nearer or above 1GB), the page will redirect from the upload form to the page showing the uploads, but the file I just uploaded doesn't show, nor does it make it to the database. I was having actual messages when I first started saying the post was too large but I changed 2 files as below and now there's no error, just nothing uploads. Where did I go wrong?

php.ini which is in the same folder as .htaccess:

```
post_max_size=2048M
upload_max_filesize=2048M
```

Also, in the .htaccess file, I added this:

```
php_value post_max_size 2048M;
php_value upload_max_filesize 2048M;

php_value client_max_body_size 2048M;
php_value client_body_buffer_size 2048M;
```

Comment: Maybe the memory on your server is insufficent? Just a guess. No error messages?

Comment: Not at all since I added the above values. Nothing in the logs either